# Don't get the accordion working with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't get the accordion working on [my page](http://mendert.nl/zeeuwseknop/pages/contact-us/):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mendert.nl/zeeuwseknop/wp-content/themes/food-cook/includes/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mendert.nl/zeeuwseknop/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mendert.nl/zeeuwseknop/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

This is my js

```
/*content accordion*/
$('.accordion').each(function(){
    var acc = $(this).attr("rel") * 2;
    $(this).find('.accordion-inner:nth-child(' + acc + ')').show();
    $(this).find('.accordion-inner:nth-child(' + acc + ')').prev().addClass("active");
});

$('.accordion .accordion-title').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).parent().find('.accordion-title').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.accordion-title').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(200);
    }
    return false;
});
```

I use a shortcode through my php functions to inset this in my page:

```
// [container]
function accordion($atts, $content=null, $code) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'open' => '1',
    'title' => 'Title'
), $atts));

if (!preg_match_all("/(.?)\[(accordion-item)\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/accordion-item\])?(.?)/s", $content, $matches)) {
    return do_shortcode($content);
} 
else {
    $output = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $matches[3][$i] = shortcode_parse_atts($matches[3][$i]);

        $output .= '<div class="accordion-title"><a href="#">' . $matches[3][$i]['title'] . '</a></div><div class="accordion-inner">' . do_shortcode(trim($matches[5][$i])) .'</div>';
    }
    return '<h3 class="accordion_h3">'.$title.'</h3><div class="accordion" rel="'.$open.'">' . $output . '</div>';

}
```

}`

Comment: And you wrapped that code in `jQuery(function($) { ... });`, as this looks like Wordpress ?

Comment: Jep its wordpress in this statement: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });`

Comment: I think you're meant to include the ui script after the jquery script.  Also you haven't closed some of your accordion inner divs

Comment: ^^ what he said, jQuery UI goes after jQuery, but that shouldn't be an issue with Wordpress as it should figure that out by itself if you included the script properly by using wp_enque_script

Comment: There are a ton of great WordPress plugins for adding [accordions](http://wordpress.org/plugins/accordion-shortcodes/). You could use one of those, or maybe take a look at some of their code to see how it works.

Comment: The code is included by using wp_engue_script. I dont see where I haven't closing a accordion-inner div

Comment: Is it possible that it doesn't work with some other code?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing these two files - markerclusterer.js and favico.js (404 Error) , so those errors block your accordion.

Comment: on your page load open your browser console (for Firefox browser - Firebug is a good option), there you can see all of your ui errors.Make sure you open the console then load your page